# How come I cannot call the content url in this css code wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to use the content URL in CSS for wordpress. See the following code, what did I do wrong?

```css
#object-nav ul li a:before{
    content:url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/home.png';?>);                 
}
```

Comment: Where did you put this code? IT has to be interpreted by PHP, so it can be placed in a `.css` file.

Comment: If this is a stylesheet within your theme, you can just use relative paths to reference the image. `content: url('images/home.png');`

Comment: it is a stylesheet, but  url('images/home.png'); is not working, I have to put the whole path like http://website/wp-content/themes/childtheme/image.png, but I just don't want to put the whole path in case I change on the future

Answer (score 0):

A.L. mistyped a word in his comment. He meant it **cannot** be placed in your stylesheet. PHP code in CSS files is not interpreted so it is read as is. In other words, your instruction does not make sense as it is not converted. 
Anyway: you could use a root-relative url, like this:

```
#object-nav ul li a:before{
    content:url('/wp-content/themes/nameofyourtheme/images/home.png');                 
}
```

If you move your site to another domain, it will still work.

Comment: Thanks for your time. your code is not working for me, I have to add my website before /wp-content/. That is why i don't like it, if I change domain,  I have to change it one by one.

Comment: Or use SASS with variables. You change it once, it's reflected everywhere in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in your theme's folder called something like `mystyle.css.php`.

Start it with the following line of code:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/css'); ?>
```

Then move all your css rules where you want to use php to create variables into this file and remove them from your primary `style.css`.

Near the beginning of your `style.css` file add:

```
@import url('mystyle.css.php`);`
```